# How does Assembly.Load(byte[]) work?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, plugins, .net-assembly

I was just wondering what happens if I was to load the same assembly bytes twice within a web app.

For example I have this code

```
byte[] assem = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(appRoot + "/Plugins/Plugin.dll");

var loadedAssem = Assembly.Load(assem);

var plugin = loadedAssem.CreateInstance("Plugin.ThePlugin") as IPlugin;
```

I ran this code and on the first request I assume it would load the assembly into ram ( or the http runtime appdomain? ) and then I can create instances of whatever is in there.

If I ran this code again, say on the second request what would happen to the assembly on the first request?

Would is still exist in ram? if so how does it differentiate between the two assemblies? or does it overwrite the previously declare classes?

This is for my understanding, as like I do in PHP its not just a case of "require_once".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will load two distinct copies of the assembly, each of which can be used from your application.  The types in each assembly are distinct types and will not inter-operate with one-another.  For instance, if you take a Widget from Copy1 and try to pass it to a method that takes a Widget on Copy2, this will cause a runtime failure.  It is not possible to unload assemblies once they have been loaded in this way (i.e. into your main AppDomain.)

---

Regarding instantiation:

- If you use Assembly.CreateInstance (as shown in your post), this will create it from the Assembly instance you used to make the call.
- If you use an Activator.CreateInstance that takes a string, you need to specify the assembly name.  Since both loaded assemblies will have the same name in this case, it will use assembly resolution rules, which, I think by default, will favor the first match (so the assembly you loaded first.)  I'm not certain of this.  You can hook the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event to provide your own prioritization and make it use your most-recently-loaded assembly.

Comment: I see, when you say they are distinct if I was to load two copies of the same assembly and the create an instance of a class like Widget.. which assembly would the class be instantiated from?

Comment: Yeah... did I really just ask that? It's late.. I should sleep lol. okay so if I have these 2 copies loaded and I only need to use one of them and have the other unloaded i would need to load them into a separate appdomain and unload that domain?

Comment: @Richard, yes, but that's not nearly as easy as it sounds.  If you want to learn more about AppDomains, read up on MarshalByRefObject, transparent proxying and AppDomain isolation.  There are a lot of subtleties involved in allowing for that isolation.  If you don't anticipate reloading very often, it's much simpler to just load a copy.  Also, if you're a web app, your main AppDomain might be unloaded frequently anyway (not sure exactly how you're set up.)

Comment: @DanBryant Okay I'll read up a bit more, also is there a performance hit for making cross appdomain calls? if so is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Richard, cross-domain calls are proxied, so there is definitely a performance hit.  Reference objects that cross the domain boundary must derive from MarshalByRefObject and you should think of them almost like remote objects.  All other objects must be serializable and will then be marshaled by value (using serialization to create a copy.)  To deal with this overhead, you follow the same types of practices you'd do when designing an inter-process remoting solution, by minimizing the marshaling required.

Comment: @DanBryant ah I see, thank you for this too, you have cleared these things up but I will do some more reading on app domains and see where I get too! :)

Comment: Please read Suzanne Cook's articles on Assembly loading before getting into too much of trouble - i.e. starting from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx . Reiterating - as Dan said, loading the same assembly twice in the same AppDomain will bring you plenty of hard to find troubles.